# c# storing images into sql multiple selection

Tags: c#, sql, filestream, multipleselection, storing-data

I want to store images into sql using c# application. So I have this code, and multiple selection is true. I know that I need to use an array filenames. Can you help me to realize it? I just need to select more than one file in folder and store thme in sql data base.

browse images:

```
 private void btnBrowseImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Sekili sec";

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "E:\\IKA";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
           // openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 10;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    txtImagePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName; 
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

file to binary

```
byte[] ReadImageToBytes(string sPath)
        {
            //Initialize byte array with a null value initially.
            byte[] data = null;

            //Use FileInfo object to get file size.
            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);
            long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

            //Open FileStream to read file
            FileStream fStream = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, 
                                                    FileAccess.Read);

            //Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

            data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
            return data;
        }
```

saving them in sql:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Read Image Bytes into a byte array
                byte[] imageSampleData = ReadImageToBytes(txtImagePath.Text);

                //Initialize SQL Server Connection
             //   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(txtConnectionString.Text);

                String strConnString = "Data Source=1.1.1.1;Initial Catalog=Test1;User Id=dffr;Password=dffr;";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                //Set insert query
                string query = "INSERT INTO tblImages (FullPath,MyImageSample) values(@FullPath, @MyImageSample)";

                //Initialize SqlCommand object for insert.
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FullPath",
                                            (object)txtImagePath.Text));

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyImageSample",
                                                    (object)imageSampleData));

                //Open connection and execute insert query.
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();


            }
            catch 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error while saving image.", "Error");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `FileNames` property to get the list of selected files.

```
 foreach(string filename in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
 {
    //1. read file 
    //2. store content of file into database.
 }
```

Comment: what should be in the body of a loop?

Comment: it give me a mistake "'openFileDialog1' does not exist in the current context".